# Apply Sieve in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-classification, spatial-filter

Without applying a filter function like the mode or similar, I want to apply a sieve to a raster with two classes.

Let's say I have a raster with pixel values 0 and 1; I want to remove groups of pixels smaller than 4. For instance, if I have two adjacent pixels with value 1 sounding by pixels with value 0, I want to assign value 0 to those two pixels in GEE. This would be equivalent to the sieve function in QGis.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have `0` and `1`, you can simply do this:

```
var minPixels = 4
var count = image.connectedPixelCount(minPixels)

var filtered = image
  .where(count.lt(minPixels), image.not())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6799c1e1f2d73a85c65ca4cfc34121ca

Comment: Thanks, Daniel; I have tried your code with a raster with 0 and 1, but I do not see any difference between the filtered and original images. Here is the code you provided using a new image: https://code.earthengine.google.com/34597b979cfda794761fb61b7ecbbde9

Comment: `connectedPixelCount()` is scale dependent. Your imagery is 30m, mine was 10m. So you will have to perform this at a different zoom level. When you export your results, you'd presumably set the scale to 30m and the filtering would work as expected.  https://code.earthengine.google.com/ab9a3aa53d70c073c786f58839ede2a6